# Template template parameter, interior parameter not fixed

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class called MATRIX that takes a single parameter T. I would like to write a function that takes a MATRIX and returns a T valued output. MATRIX typedefs T as elem_type in its implementation. My initial attempt at doing this was:

```
template<template<typename> class MATRIX>
class MyClass
{
...
    MATRIX<>::elem_type myfun(const MATRIX<>& m1);
}
```

This results in an error "argument list for template template parameter "MATRIX" is missing", which makes sense looking at it. The problem is that I have no idea what to put there. I could specify float, for example, but I would like this function to work regardless of whether the parameter of MATRIX is float, double, uint_16, or whatever else. Is it possible to do this without specifically enumerating all of the possible parameters for MATRIX?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of solving this problem is by having `MyClass` take a single template parameter, and then explicitly specialize it on `MATRIX`.

```
template <typename>
class MyClass;

template <template <typename> class MATRIX, typename T>
class MyClass<MATRIX<T>>
{
    // ...
    typename MATRIX<T>::elem_type myfun(const MATRIX<T>& m1);
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ATKrekTPMVbHxZCg)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. The wandbox example was particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a template template parameter, it is necessary to provide another template argument which can be used to instantiate the template template parameter.

```
template<template<typename> class MATRIX, typename ElemenType>
class MyClass
{
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
template<template<typename> class MATRIX, typename ElemenType>
class MyClass
{
   typename MATRIX<ElementType>::elem_type myfun(const MATRIX<>& m1);
}
```